# Delete App from private play store iFrame

Tags: android, google-api, google-play, google-play-services, android-management-api

Is the `Delete` option removed from Private Play Store iFrame ? It was available a couple of weeks ago. Please have a look at the SS below.

[image]

If it's removed then option do we have to delete an app?

If I unpublish it from developer console under Pricing & distribution, the app shows up in the Private Play store as`Not Available Yet`

[image]

The `Delete` option was previously available, not sure why it has disappeared all of a sudden?

Help appreciated,

Thanks